# Error when trying to import Scipy module to Blender

Tags: python, scripting

There is an error when I want to import the scipy module into blender through the anaconda directory. How can I fix this error?

Code:

```
import sys

scipy_path = "C:\Users\ALAFG\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages"

if not scipy_path in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(scipy_path)    

import scipy
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/ALAFG/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/site- 
packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
File "/Users/ALAFG/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/site- 
packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps you have a different version of python installed on your system than the one being used by Blender.

To keep things simple, I usually install scipy into Blender's python.

I run the [get_pip.py](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiVwJrTvrDaAhWNAHwKHSJOB44QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbootstrap.pypa.io%2Fget-pip.py&usg=AOvVaw0zKVO_zW0nkF7s0zdjWFNj) file in Blender's text editor.

Then I install using pip by running this in the text editor:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'scipy'])
```

Doing this will allow you to `import scipy` without needing to append any path.

Depending on how you have Blender installed, you may need to run Blender with administrator priveledges in order to do this.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used this code and there is no Error now!

Comment: I can't import `pip`: `ImportError: No module named 'pip'`. I also tried `pip3` but it didn't work.

Comment: You have to download the get-pip.py file and run that in Blender's text editor first. That will install pip inside Blender.