# How to load external modules/packages into blender python

Tags: python, scripting

I have a bunch of modules that I had previously installed using `pip` to my system `python 2.7`. What do I need to do in order to be able to import this module in the blender python console, as well as within my python scripts in blender? (The module in question is called ProDy).

**EDIT:** I installed `pyenv` and installed the same version of python as my blender version (`3.5.3`) uses through it. I then made this version active, and installed the packages I need with `pip3 install`. I can load the packages in terminal, but not in the blender python console. What am I missing?

Comment: You'll have to upgrade to Python 3 first.

Comment: So if I python 3 and the modules for python 3, that would work in blender?

Comment: @dr.Sybren I tried this, please see the updates in the post.

Comment: I answered [a similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106099/error-when-trying-to-import-scipy-module-to-blender/106102#106102) not too long ago about installing scipy. The instructions should work for you too if you're using Windows.

Comment: @doakey3 Oh cool, thanks! I'm using mac, but I guess it should still be the same. One question though: would I have to do this every time I launch blender?

Comment: get-pip.py will install pip. Then using pip should install the python library you want. You'd only need to do this once. I'm not experienced with Mac, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 7):

### **Update for the Snap-released Blender versions (e.g. 2.93)**

In general, and for good reasons, [it is not possible to modify `snap` installations](https://askubuntu.com/a/919098).

This means that the procedure below will first try to install pip and the packages at the default location inside snap, but will silently fail due to the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

Then, it will install the dependencies in some other "default" location allowed (in my Ubuntu20.04 this was `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`), and this is likely a place that Blender is not expecting. As a consequence, installation will be "successful" but Blender will still be unable to find the dependencies.

To diagnose this, open the Blender Python console and check `sys.path` to see which paths is Blender expecting, and `pip show <PACKAGE>` to see where has the package been installed. If the path is not in the expected list, it won't be found.

There are a few ideas to fix this:

- Force our way into snap through the OS and install files there (bad idea and likely to be a headache)
- Use `subprocess` to install into snap using Blender's Python, as discussed [here](https://developer.blender.org/T71856)
- Tell Blender where to look for our new files

From all 3, I personally think that option 3 is the simplest and most versatile one. We can see that Blender's [Python options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) now include the following flag:

> `--python-use-system-env`: Allow Python to use system environment variables such as PYTHONPATH and the user site-packages directory.

##### In my case, the solution was simply to install pip and the packages as before, and run Blender as before, but adding the `--python-use-system-env` flag when running Blender, to tell that we want to look for dependencies outside snap.

This worked like a charm for my system, but if it doesn't, an alternative is to add the desired path to `sys.path` before importing (e.g. by appending the path string or by updating `$PYTHONPATH`).

Hope this helps!

---

### Original solution

For pip-installable dependencies (like PyPI or wheels), all you need to do is the following:

1. Locate your Blender's Python binary path, let's call it `<BPYTHON>` (in my case `2.80/python/bin/python3.7m` at the Blender installation). The path can be retrieved from blender itself, by running the following inside the Blender Python terminal:

```
import sys
sys.executable
# Alternatively run the following one-liner, if the version is new enough
blender -b --python-expr "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

2. Run the following to enable pip operations in bpython:

```
<BPYTHON> -m ensurepip
<BPYTHON> -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

3. Now any time you want to install a package simply call pip from bpython:

```
<BPYTHON> -m pip install <YOUR_PACKAGE>  # no --user needed
<BPYTHON> -m pip install <PATH/TO/WHEEL>.whl  # also works with wheels as expected
```

As usual, you just have to install a package once and uninstalling works the analogous way.

Blender's Python has its own environment, so this procedure will install the dependencies there (in my case the `2.80/python` folder). AFAIK this will work irrespectively of your OS, system's Python version and Blender location so I found this to be most convenient. You can encounter some issues if installing cython-related packages like `tkinter` but this can also be fixed as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050748).

Let me know if this works out!
Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Cool! thanks for the info. How is that? I checked Blender's `sys.path` but didn't find any clear pointers

Comment: Works like a charm in blender 3.3.3, in windows just add to your shortcut property in target : <your install path of blender>\blender.exe --python-use-system-env

Answer (score 0):

Just figured I would add my own solution based on @fr_andres to make using the
`snap` based Blender version a bit cleaner:

In Blender 3.4, `sys.path` includes a few additional paths in the home directory:

- `${HOME}/.config/blender/3.4/addons`
- `${HOME}/.config/blender/3.4/addons/modules`

I'm not sure what the original intent behind the `modules` directory is, but one
clever use of it is to install all extra Python modules there. Additionally,
`pip` has some additional support for this using the `--target=` flag:

```
pip3 install --target=${HOME}/.config/blender/3.4/scripts/addons/modules matplotlib scipy
```

At least for me, this turned out to be the simplest approach.