# How to use bpy to import a .mat (MatLab) file into blender's python interface?

Tags: python, scripting, import

I looked around on Google, and found that python has support for this through the `scipy` module. According to [this StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python) page, all you need to do is:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
```

When I try this in the python interface in blender though, I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`

Is there a way to get this module to work, or any other way to import a .mat file into bpy?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to install scypi in Blender, or make Blender use the system Python. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161894/how-to-import-scipy-in-blender  or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106099/error-when-trying-to-import-scipy-module-to-blender

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed the links you gave me, and installed scipy, but if I try to import scipy inside blender it still gives the ModuleNotFoundError... I have tried it in multiple ways now and everytime I try to install scipy it tells me "Requirement already satisfied", saying that scipy is already installed. Why can Blender not see it?

Comment: Did you install it inside Blender using the Blender console?

Comment: @RonJensen
Yes I ran the get-pip.py file inside the python text editor inside blender, and afterwards I ran these commands inside the python console inside blender: 
`>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install', 'scipy'])`
From that I got the following error:
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.92\\2.92\\python\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy'
Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.`
I don't know what to do with this though, as I have no idea how to add '--user' to this...

Comment: Windows isn't letting you install because the folder is protected. Just for this step you can try running Blender as administrator.

Comment: @RonJensen Thank you for all the help so far! I thought of doing that as well, but unfortunately this error came up while I already was running Blender as administrator already... I think it could maybe work if I can somehow add the '--user' argument to the command, so if you have any tips on how to do that I would really appreciate that!

Comment: did you try `["install", "scipy", "--user"]` which would emulate the required pip cli command.  (or navigate to folder and run pip from cli as admin)  There are a number of posts on installing 3rd party modules. My 2c worth is look at making a virtual env running same python version as blender, and point blenders python to it.

Comment: @batFINGER I hadn't tried `pip.main["install", "scipy", "--user"]` yet, but unfortunately when I do, I get the following error: `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`... I barely understand what I am doing, as I am very inexperienced with this stuff, so I don't really understand what you say in the rest of your post. If you have any idea what went wrong when I ran that command I would love to hear it! Thanks.

Comment: `pip.main([...])`  Suggest googling python error messages if unsure of their meaning.

Comment: @batFINGER aaah sorry for my negligence. The command worked, and it said it `Successfully installed scipy-1.6.3`. The only problem now is that if I try the `import scipy` command, it still gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`... How is that even possible if it was literally installed through the blender python console? I already googled this many times, but then I get back to where I started, so your help is the only lead I have right now haha

Comment: Not on windows.  The "user" folder used by pip is not added to python path by blender python (`sites.py`) Installing using --user installs on linux to `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`  add corresponding path for windows (look it up in pip docs) to `sys.path`

Comment: @batFINGER I added that to my blender path using the append command, but still no dice. I feel like blender can't see the package for some reason.